# Are there any use cases when it is acceptable to use Spring beans created by constructor call?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am pretty new to Spring and I study using "Spring in Action" (fourth edition) by Craig Walls. The interest is not only on how to write code that is working, but also on the correct principles of using Spring.

Regarding the following piece of code from page 142, Listing 5.6:

```
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() throws Exception {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view().name("home"));
    }
}
```

My questions are generated by the following thoughts:

1. The general understanding is that Spring uses Dependency Injection as a way to reduce the management overhead of object dependencies, increase modularity, simplify testing and code reuse. However, doesn't it imply that beans must be created and managed by the container? Since I started reading on the subject, the first detail that I memorized stated that `new` should never appear in a well-written piece of code that follows DI.
2. Could this be a solution in case we want to test a `Stateful` bean? I mean, if there are multiple independent tests to be run on the same instance, each of them testing the same state of the bean. Even though I found out that there is a suitable annotation for doing this (`@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`).
3. Is there another use case that is difficult or impossible to solve otherwise (except for using `new`)?

A more 'to the letter' implementation would use `@ContextConfiguration` to specify the `ApplicationContext`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    HomeController controller;

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() throws Exception {
        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view().name("home"));
    }
}
```

Comment: *Is there another use case that is difficult or impossible to solve otherwise*. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @CKing I mean: is there any case where we don't have alternatives and we must create beans by using the explicit constructor (like bean = new Bean(...)). In the book example and question #2 I found alternatives, so I was wondering if there are other situations where new is the only way to solve a certain problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, you shouldn't use new to create Spring bean instances (otherwise they're not Spring beans anymore) in **production** code. But the whole point of DI is to let you create and manually inject your objects with fake dependencies in unit tests. So the test code here is perfectly fine.
2. Yes, each unit test is free to create its own bean instance and to populate it the way it needs to. Stateful beans are extremely rare, though. They're usually stateless.
3. Another place where using new to create a Spring bean is precisely in `@Bean`-annotated methods of configuration classes. The whole point of these methods is precisely to create and initialize the Spring beans that will then be used and injected by Spring. But again, using new in unit tests is absolutely fine, and the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this, when I think now it makes a lot of sense.